# cypher query to extract elements from property arrays

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a question about extracting specific elements from array-valued properties in Neo4j. For example if the nodes in out database each have a property 'Scores', with Scores being an integer array of length 4. Is there a way to extract the first and fourth elements of every node in a path  i.e. can we do something along the lines of -

```
start src=node(1), end =node(7)
match path=src-[*..2]-end
return extract(n in nodes(path)| n.Scores[1], n.Scores[4]);
```

p.s. I am using Neo4j 2.0.0-RC1

Comment: if cod3monk3y's solution doesn't work for you, please give us some example output you'd like to see.

Answer (score 5):

Does this work for you?

```
START src=node(1), end=node(7)
MATCH path=src-[*..2]-end
RETURN extract(n in nodes(path)| [n.Scores[0], n.Scores[3]] )
```

Basically that's creating a collection for each node of the 1st and 4th (indexes start at 0) score. See [8.2.1. Expressions in general](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-expressions.html)

> An expression in Cypher can be:
>
> ...
>
> - A collection of expressions:
>
>   `["a", "b"], [1,2,3],["a", 2, n.property, {param}], [ ].`